# How to align two containers horizontally for css?

Tags: css

I'm a beginner in CSS. I tried using display block but it didn't work.
This is not just for a center as there are many containers displayed too. I tried using margin-bottom & right but it also didn't work and became like a crossed, almost a parallel.

I am trying to align the fourth and five div. The black and red one. I'd appreciate it if you try to see my code, thank you in advance.

```css
div#first {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

div#third {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 180px;
  width: 190px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 190px;
  position: relative;
}

div#fourth {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
}

div#five {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

div#six {
  background-color: navy;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

div#hello1 {
  background-color: navy;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90px;
}

div#hello2 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 90px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  position: absolute;
}

div#hello3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90px;
  margin-left: 290px;
}

div#hello4 {
  background-color: navy;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90px;
  margin-left: 425px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="first"> </div>
<div class="content" id="third"> </div>
<div class="content" id="fourth"> </div>
<div class="content" id="five"> </div>
<div class="content" id="six"> </div>
<div class="content" id="hello1"> </div>
<div class="content" id="hello2"> </div>
<div class="content" id="hello3"> </div>
<div class="content" id="hello4"> </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APDFj.png)

Comment: Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div around the forth and fifth divs and set the display to flexbox. Then use justify-content and align-items to place your div where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that I fully get what you mean, but look at this snippet and tell me if that's what you are looking for (open the

```css
div#first{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
}

 div#third{
     background-color: blue;
     height: 180px;
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
 }

 div#fourth{
     background-color: black;
     height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
   float: left;

 }

 div#five{
     background-color:  red;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     float: left;

 }

 div#six{
     background-color: navy;
     height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
 }

 div#hello1{
      background-color: navy;
     width: 80px;
     height: 100px;
     position: absolute;
     bottom:90px;
 
 }

 div#hello2{
      background-color: orange;
     width: 200px;
     height: 100px;
     bottom:90px;
     margin-left: 85px;
     position: absolute;
 
 }

 div#hello3{
     background-color: red;
     width: 130px;
     height: 100px;
     position: absolute;
     bottom:90px;
     margin-left: 290px;
  
 }

 div#hello4{
     background-color: navy;
     width: 150px;
     height: 100px;
     position: absolute;
     bottom:90px;
     margin-left: 425px;
 
 }


#aligned {
  display : flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class = "content"   id = "first">  </div> 
<div class = "content"   id = "third">  </div> 
  <div id="aligned">
<div class = "content"   id = "fourth">  </div> 
<div class = "content"   id = "five">  </div>
    </div>
<div class = "content"   id = "six">  </div> 
</body>
```